# Infinite exponent loop - Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create a function that takes a value x, and creates a pattern like this with n+1 square root terms: sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)...

```
def func(x,n):
a = x**0.5
i = 0
while i < n:
    a = a ** (x**0.5)
    i += 1

print a
```

For example using x = 2, the function does not converge (to 2), but increases exponentially in some way, I don't understand why.

For the first iteration (i=0) it seems to be correct, as it calculates, sqrt(2)^sqrt(2), but for the second iteration (i=1) it gives me 2.0, and it keeps increasing.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say `sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)`, do you want `(sqrt(x)^sqrt(x))^sqrt(x)` or `sqrt(x)^(sqrt(x)^sqrt(x))`?

Answer (score 3):

For `sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)^sqrt(x)...` to converge, the exponentiation needs to be treated as right-associative, i.e. `sqrt(x)^(sqrt(x)^(sqrt(x)^...))`. But your code is calculating it as left-associative: `((...^sqrt(x))^sqrt(x))^sqrt(x)`.

You need to switch the order of terms in

```
a = a ** (x**0.5)
```

to

```
a = (x**0.5) ** a
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer by @interjay illustrates what the problem is with the iterative method. As an alternative, you could also use a recursive method to calculate this

```
from math import sqrt
def fun(x,n):
    if n == 0:
        return sqrt(x)
    else:
        return sqrt(x) ** fun(x, n-1)

>>> fun(2,2)
1.7608395558800285

>>> fun(2,3)
1.8409108692910108

>>> fun(2,10)
1.988711773413954

>>> fun(2,100)
2.0000000000000004
```